# Optional arguments in user input

Tags: python

I'm making a ircbot that gets discgolf data from a database. I would like to store possible commands in dictionary:

```
function_dictionary = {"get PLAYERS best round from COURSE on YEAR" : 
get_best_round,
"get PLAYERS THINGS from COURSE on YEAR" : get_things}
```

Players, courses and so on would be stored in lists.

```
PLAYERS = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
COURSES = ["course1", "course2", "course3"]
THINGS = ["birdies", "pars", "bogeys"]
YEARS = [2015, 2016, 2017]
```

If all arguments are give by user, I can replace arguments and save original values:

```
userinput = "get name1 best round from course1 on 2016"
for p in PLAYERS:
    if p in userinput:
        player = p 
        userinput = userinput.replace(p, "PLAYERS")
for c in COURSES:
    if c in userinput:
        course = c 
        userinput = userinput.replace(c, "COURSE")
for y in YEARS:
    if y in userinput:
        year = y 
        userinput = userinput.replace(y, "YEAR")
```

And then search if the command is in the dictionary:

```
for key in function_dictionary:
    if key in userinput:
        func_to_run = function_dictionary[key]

func_to_run(player, course, year)
```

How would I get this work, if one or more arguments are missing from the user input?

```
userinput1 = "get name1 best round"
```

should trigger:

```
get_best_round("name1", course = "all", year = "all")
```

and

```
userinput2 = "get best round from course1"
```

should trigger:

```
get_best_round(name = "all", "course1", year = "all")
```

and

```
userinput3 = "get birdies on 2016"
```

shoud trigger

```
get_things(name = "all", "birdies", course = "all", 2016)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some flags.

For example:

```
PLAYERS_inserted = False
for p in PLAYERS:
    if p in userinput:
        player = p
        userinput = userinput.replace(p, "PLAYERS")
        PLAYERS_inserted = True

COURSES_inserted = False
for c in COURSES:
    if c in userinput:
        course = c 
        userinput = userinput.replace(c, "COURSE")
        COURSES_inserted = True

YEARS_inserted = False
for y in YEARS:
    if y in userinput:
        year = y 
        userinput = userinput.replace(y, "YEAR")
        YEAR_inserted = True
```

And then, you just check the boolean values and call the appropriate methods.

However, I wouldn't go with this approach. It seems to have enough points of failure. Maybe search `regex` and/or construct a more concrete interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just add clauses to say if the player/course/year weren't selected in userinput then default to a value of your choice:

```
pset = False
for p in PLAYERS:
    if p in userinput:
        pset=True
        player = p 
        userinput = userinput.replace(p, "PLAYERS")
if pset==False:
     player= #value for any player
```

and repeat for course and year.